# ld can't find an available library

Tags: c++, makefile, ld

I have a problem when linking my application, `ld` could not find an available library :

```
/usr/bin/ld : could not find -lVtsUtils_0.1.5d
/usr/bin/ld : could not find -lVtsCore_0.1.5d
/usr/bin/ld : could not find -llibmysql
```

The compile line is (found through `make VERBOSE=1`) :

```
/usr/bin/c++ -g CMakeFiles/Dental.dir/main.cpp.o CMakeFiles/Dental.dir/qrc_myproject.cpp.o CMakeFiles/Dental.dir/Dental_automoc.cpp.o -o ../../../bin/debug/Dentald -L/home/naccyde/Projets/myproject/lib/linux -rdynamic /usr/lib64/libQt5Widgets.so.5.6.2 -lVtsUtils_0.1.5d -lVtsCore_0.1.5d -llibmysql /usr/lib64/libQt5Gui.so.5.6.2 /usr/lib64/libQt5Core.so.5.6.2 -Wl,-rpath,/home/naccyde/Projets/myproject/lib/linux
```

But `ls -l /home/naccyde/Projets/myproject/lib/linux` show :

```
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 naccyde naccyde  2067984  2 mars  17:34 VtsCore_0.1.5d.so
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 naccyde naccyde 10984568  2 mars  17:34 VtsNavigation_0.1.5d.so
-rwxrwxrwx. 1 naccyde naccyde  4760776  2 mars  17:34 VtsUtils_0.1.5d.so
```

I can't understand why it does not work.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Libraries on Linux (or all POSIX systems) need to be prefixed with `lib`. So a dynamic library called `VtsCore_0.1.5d` should have the filename `libVtsCore_0.1.5d.so`.

Rename your libraries appropriately. Or pass the full path to the actual library files (e.g. `/home/naccyde/Projets/myproject/lib/linux/VtsCore_0.1.5d.so`) to the linker.